# what is the best server to make chat app in android?

Tags: xmpp

I want to develop a chat app for android users app will be native and I want to know which will be more easy for me using firebase or XMPP?

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Firebase

Firebase is a real-time database that uses Websockets and MongoDB. You are given full control over the database schema and all the code that’s used to interact with the server is defined on the client side. Here are some benefits and drawbacks:

Performance Websockets and MongoDB allow high performance and a lot of concurrent connections

Flexibility You can make the data structures you need. If you wanted to send new message types like a survey message, you could. You could also support WebRTC and use Firebase for signalling.

Persistence You can automatically back up messages on the server so if a user loses their device, they could just synch with server and get their messages back.

Frameworks There are existing frameworks that already provide messaging on Firebase. The Chat SDK has a framework for iOS and Android which are available for free on Github.

Fat client All the messaging logic is defined in client code which means to add a new platform, you have to re-write all the code.

Not Specialised Firebase doesn’t define any protocols so you would have to invent this yourself. You would have to decide what information to include on a message, and how to structure the database

## XMPP

XMPP is a server that is specifically designed for messaging. As far as one exists, it is the industry standard messaging protocol. It’s used by big companies to power messaging for millions of users. It’s used in Skype, Facebook messenger, WhatsApp and Google Hangouts.

Performance XMPP servers can be clustered scaling to tens of millions of users

Open Source There are a number of excellent open source XMPP servers - ejabberd, OpenFire, Prosody

Defined Protocol XMPP is a well defined protocol. This means that in theory, any XMPP app can function with any XMPP server

Thin Client The XMPP server provides all the business logic and the client just sends and interprets a stream of XML messages. This makes it easier to deploy on multiple platforms.

Hard to setup XMPP servers can be difficult to setup and maintain

Complex development Developing a client for an XMPP server can be much more difficult and time consuming that using Firebase because the protocol seems dense and archaic at times

Bugs Unfortunately the protocol isn’t always followed correctly which can lead to bugs